# Django creates an extra unwanted entry in many-2-many intermediate table

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I have a many-2-many relationship between Flight and Passenger. When I try to assign a passenger to a flight object, Django seems to add an extra entry to the intermediate table.

Here are the models:

```
class Passenger(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.IntegerField()


class Flight(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField('flight time')
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    passengers = models.ManyToManyField(
        to=Passenger,
        symmetrical=True,
        related_name='flights',
        blank=True,
    )
```

Say the intermediate table looks like this, with passenger
[image: Intermediate database screenshot]

Say `flight_object` is a Flight with ID=1, and `passenger_object` is a Passenger with ID=2, when I run `flight_object.passengers.add(passenger_object)` Django adds 2 entries to the intermediate table in the database. The table now looks like this:
[image: Screenshot of intermediate table]

Both entries with ID=1 and 2 should be there, but 3 is incorrect, and the `flight_id` foreign key is for a completely different flight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of `symmetrical=True`. You shouldn't create symmetrical `ManyToMany` relation to any model other than `self`.

According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical), when using `symmetrical=True`, Django tries to insert the symmetrical record in the `through` table.